# Updating Drupal Core Using Drush Says It Updated Successfully But Does Not?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drush

I am trying to update a clients Drupal site using Drush from 7.64 to 7.67. I go into my project folder using puTTy and run these commands:

```
drush vset --exact maintenance_mode 1

drush cache-clear all

drush pm-update drupal

drush vset --exact maintenance_mode 0

drush cache-clear all
```

When a run the update command I get the following message:

```
Project drupal was updated successfully. Installed version is now 7.67.
```

But after, when I go to my websites admin section and check the updates section it still says Drupal core is on 7.64 and not on 7.67.

I ran the above commands a few times to see if it was just a coincidence, but it still would not update Drupal core.

Comment: Did you check php & mysql logs ?

Comment: Linux user used have all rights to modify files and folders ?

Comment: @Fky I was able to update modules using the above method, the core is the only thing that won't update

Comment: @user9664977 maybe you can find solution with this following documentation https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/update/updating-drupal-using-drush

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the `updb` command in your steps. Here's my revised version of your steps with it included.

```
drush vset --exact maintenance_mode 1

drush cache-clear all

drush pm-update drupal

drush updb -y

drush vset --exact maintenance_mode 0

drush cache-clear all
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue moving from 7.75 to 7.98. My issue was that all the folders inside my drupal directory, did not have the correct owner. I used drush pm-update drupal command but the execution could not modified the inside folders (themes, includes, modules, etc) because of the wrong owner.

After updating the ownership of those folders I was able to update Drupal successfully.